# What's the purpose of non-wettable soldering iron tips?

Tags: soldering

While looking for a very fine soldering iron tip, I came across [this](https://www.testequipmentdepot.com/weller/accessories/tips/rt-micro-tips/rt-micro-active-soldering-tip-conical-0-1-mm-not-wettable-rtm001cnw.htm) tip. It apparently has no wettable surface like every other tip I've used does, and I struggle to see why this might be a desirable characteristic.

Has anyone ever used one of these non-wettable tips? What did you use it for? If not, can you even think of a situation where you would want a non-wettable tip?

Comment: Removing small solder bridges maybe? All I could come up with.

Comment: Heat staking...that said, that does not look like a heat staking tip.

Comment: @DKNguyen While this particular tip isn't suitable for heat staking, I suppose there's no particular reason a heat-staking tip should be wettable--though given that the non-wettable tip is more expensive than the wettable version (in the cases I can find where there are wettable and non-wettable tips with the same geometry), there may be price reasons to make it a regular wettable tip.

Comment: @Hearth But can you make a wetting tip that doesn't get ratty when hot? My understanding is heat staking tips are chrome plated. I assume that protects from oxidation and prevents plastic from sticking, but I've never handled one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you refer to the link you posted, there is statement `for 0201 / 0204 components`.

These components are very small and will cling to solder by surface tension.

So, there is an advantage to have a solder phobic tip to work with.

That way you can be confident that the soldering iron does not pull components off the board during the soldering process.

Comment: It might be bad technique, but I tend to rely on the solder adhering to the tip in order to get good heat conduction. Guess I'd have to figure out a better way if I had to use tiny components!

Comment: @Hearth It's next to impossible to avoid getting it on the tip when working with smaller components, but it isn't ideal since the flux core will quickly vaporize and the result is small "antennas" of solder sticking out from the pad when you withdraw the tip. And then you must go back and re-do the joints by adding external flux.

Comment: This answer does not seem to address the issue. Any small SMT component (0402, 0603. 0805, even 1206) will cling to solder, and a normal wettable tip will pull that component if it is not held using tweezers. The non-wetted tip does not transfer much of heat to pads, so it seems useless and does  not work, for me at least. Weller does make a 0.1mm tip (T0050101799), which looks wettable, but it needs a different type of iron handpiece (pico series).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at one (heat staking tips specifically) for a while to heat connectors with a cup for solder and wire so I could heat it from the outside without leaving solder residue on the shell. I never got one though.